# No entiendo como usar un struct desde una clase

Tags: c++, dev-c++, class

Como dice el titulo no entiendo como guardar informacion dentro de un struct a partir de una clase, tengo el siguiente problema:

Se dispone del siguiente tipo de dato:
struct alumno{string nombre; float nota;};

En base al mismo se desea crear una clase Curso para modelar el cursado de una
materia. La clase deberá contener el nombre de la materia y la cantidad de
alumnos en el curso junto con una lista de los mismos. Proponga los siguientes
métodos:
a. Constructores y destructores según lo considere conveniente.
b. Un método que permita agregar un Alumno.
c. Un método que determine el promedio del curso.
d. Un método que devuelva la calificación más alta y el nombre del alumno
que la obtuvo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct alumno{
    string nombre;
    float nota;
    
};
class curso{
    
private:
    int cant;
public:
    curso (int);
    void AgregarAlumno();
    void PromCurso();
    void CalifMasalta();
    
};

curso::curso(int c){
    cant=c;
    
}
void curso::AgregarAlumno(){
    vector<alumno> v(cant);
    alumno a;
    for(int i=0;i<cant;i++) {
    cout<<i<<"- Ingresar nombre y nota"<<endl;
    cin>>a[i].nombre>>a[i].nota;
    }
}

void curso::PromCurso(){
    int suma=0;
    for(int i=0;i<cant;i++) {
        suma=suma+a[i].nota;
    }
    
    cout<<"El promedio del curso es : "<<suma/cant<<endl;

}

void curso::CalifMasalta(){
    
    int mayor=0;
    int pos;
    for(int i=0;i<cant;i++) {
        if(a[i].nota>mayor){
            mayor=a[i].nota;
            pos=i;
        }
        
        
    }
    cout<<"La mayor nota fue: "<<mayor<<" por el alumno: "<<a[pos].nombre<<endl;
    
}
int main() {
    
    curso c(3);
    void AgregarAlumno();
    void PromCurso();
    void CalifMasalta();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores.

Si una variable local en una función, solo podrás acceder a ella mientras la función esté en ejecución.

Por ejemplo, en la función `AgregarAlumno` tienes un vector donde supongo que quieres guardar los alumnos. Para que "siga viviendo", la forma más simple es hacerlo miembro de la clase:

```
class curso {

private:

    vector<alumno> alumnos;
    ...
};
```

Desde entonces podrás acceder al vector `alumnos` (o el nombre que prefieras ponerle) desde cualquier método. Por cierto, no necesitas guardar el número de alumnos en una variable. El vector ya se encarga de llevar la cuenta.

También falta agregar el alumno al vector.

---

Lo mismo pasa con la variable local `a` de la función `AgregarAlumno`. Y además, intentas acceder al elemento en la posición `i` de `a` pero no es un arreglo.

---

La consigna te pide un método que permita agregar **un alumno**, no todos.

---

En la función para calcular el promedio acumulas las notas en una variable de tipo entero. Estás perdiendo la información de los decimales al hacer la suma. Puedes arreglarlo cambiándole el tipo.

---

Te quedaría algo así:

```
class curso {
   private:
    vector<alumno> alumnos;

   public:
    void AgregarAlumno();
    void PromCurso();
    void CalifMasalta();
};

void curso::AgregarAlumno() {
    alumno a;

    cout << "Ingresar nombre y nota" << endl;
    cin >> a.nombre >> a.nota;
    alumnos.push_back(a);
}

void curso::PromCurso() {
    float suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.size(); i++) {
        suma += a[i].nota;
    }

    cout << "El promedio del curso es : " << suma / alumnos.size() << endl;
}

void curso::CalifMasalta() {
    int mayor = 0;
    int pos;
    for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.size(); i++) {
        if (alumnos[i].nota > mayor) {
            mayor = a[i].nota;
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "La mayor nota fue: " << mayor << " por el alumno: " << alumnos[pos].nombre << endl;
}
```